# How to define function/component that can error message display generally?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios, chakra-ui

I want to define a function or component that can display the error reason in the response directly on the front-end via the `toast` component in chakra-ui when the back-end response has an error. Here is my definition.

```js
const request = axios.create({
  baseURL: [],
  timeout: 5000
})

export const error= (msg: string) => {
  toast({
    position: 'top',
    status: 'error',
    duration: 2000,
    description: msg
  })
}

request.interceptors.response.use(
  response => {
    if (response.status !== 'ok') {
        error(response.reason)
    }
    return response
  },
  error => {
      console.log('err' + error) // for debug
      return Promise.reject(error)
  }
)
```

The library I'm using is axios, and I want to define a response interceptor that intercepts the response and then calls error to display the error message based on the message of the response.

However, because react specifies React Hook (`useToast`/`toast`) cannot be called at the top level, which causes compile error. How should I implement the above functionality?

Answer (score 0):

To be able to use the toaster outside of a react component, you need to use Chakra UI's `createStandaloneToast` function, which returns a `ToastContainer` component and `toast` function.

From their [docs](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/components/toast/usage#standalone-toasts),

```
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import { createStandaloneToast } from '@chakra-ui/react'

const { ToastContainer, toast } = createStandaloneToast()

// render the ToastContainer in your React root
const rootElement = document.getElementById('root')
ReactDOM.createRoot(yourRootElement).render(
  <>
    <App />
    <ToastContainer />
  </>,
)

toast({
  title: 'An error occurred.',
  description: 'Unable to create user account.',
  status: 'error',
  duration: 9000,
  isClosable: true,
})
```

They also make the note that if you made any customization to your theme, you need to pass that information into `createStandaloneToast`, otherwise things will look weird.

If you move

```
import { createStandaloneToast } from '@chakra-ui/react'

const { ToastContainer, toast } = createStandaloneToast()
```

to a separate file and add

```
export { ToastContainer, toast }
```

then you'll be able to import that in any file where you need to call `toast`.